# Installing git for a single user

Tags: macos, git, osx-mountain-lion

I'm going to borrow another computer for a while so I've copied my project directory to the new computer and now I need to install Git on it.

Is it possible to install [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and the [Github GUI client](http://mac.github.com/) on OSX Mountain Lion for a single user? Second question, how do I uninstall Git?

Comment: When you say "for a single user", do you mean you don't have admin rights on that machine? If that is the case, things are probably going to be a bit difficult, at least with the [Git OS X Installer](https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/).

Comment: I have admin rights, I just don't want to "mess up" the user account that belongs to the owner of the computer by installing a bunch of applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Git installer for OS X](https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/), it'll do a system-wide install. This means you need admin rights for it to run.

However, the installer will write everything to `/usr/local/git`. This path (`/usr/local`) is not used in a default OS X installation. Per the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html), you can place anything there which just belongs to one user, and safely remove it again without affecting anything else.

If you ever want to uninstall Git – at least the version from the Git Installer – run the following:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/git
rm /etc/paths.d/git
rm /etc/manpaths.d/git
```

The first folder is the one containing all the programs. `paths.d/git` is just a file that enables the `git` for every shell's path, and `manpaths.d/git` does the same for the manpage.

Removing the above files and folders will have *no* implications whatsoever for the other user accounts.

---

The [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/) application can simply be installed to `/User/your-username/Applications` instead of `/Applications`.  You might have to create the folder if it doesn't exist yet.

Other users won't be aware of this application at all. Its settings will be stored in `~/Library`, which also belongs to your user.

Comment: Is it the same if I install it using [this](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) instead?

Comment: It's the exact same (installer) file—it even points to the Google Code repository.